# How to make Kepler.gl plots consistent

Tags: python, plot, geospatial, kepler.gl

I'm using kepler.gl to create some geographical plots.
I want to create some setting for the plot and than set these as default for when I run the cell containing that plot.

These are the steps:

1. I copied the `conf` from Kepler.gl website from Share>Share Map> Map Config.
2. I pasted the copied text to my python notebook cell in the variable
   `conf`

```
conf = {. . .} # copied from the website after setting the correct visualization
```

3. I replaced all true with True, false with False etc.
4. In the notebook I created a map and set the config

```
from keplergl import KeplerGl
import json

map1 = KeplerGl()
map1.add_data(data=gpd.read_file('my.geojson'), name='name1')
map1.config = conf
```

5. I modified the label property in `conf` so that it would be equal to the name property inside the `add_data` function

Finally when I show the plot using
`map1`
It shows a basic plot of my geojson without any of the configurations in `conf`.

NB.
The geojson file I uploaded in Kepler.gl is the same file I used in KeplerGL() python function

I read online that it can be due to the IDs of the datasets but I don't understand how to make those IDs the same since I'm using the same dataset.

[Here's the documentation](https://docs.kepler.gl/docs/keplergl-jupyter#wkt), personally I didn't manage to find the answer to my question in there but maybe there is and I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the `name` that you define in the
`map1.add_data()`to the `dataId` property (instead of the `label`) of your config.

So in your exapmpe:

```
"dataId": ["name1"]
```

*Important: Depending on your style settings the field `"dataId"` might exist more than once. You need to replace the value of all instances.*